# how to builed a 9->1 multiplixer using 3->1 multiplixer?

Tags: vhdl

i am trying to build a Multiplexer  9-1 using 4 Multiplexer  3-1 ,
i need to use 4 sel entries and 9 entries and one output.
here is how i wrote the 3->1 Multiplexer :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity my_mux_1 is
    port(inputt : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) ;
        selector : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        outputt : out std_logic ) ;
end my_mux_1;
architecture arc_my_mux_1 of my_mux_1 is
begin
    outputt <=  inputt(0) when selector="00" else 
               inputt(1) when selector="01" else
                inputt(2) when selector="10" else
                '0';
end arc_my_mux_1 ;
```

now i am having troubles writing the 9->1 multiplixer , i basicly wrote this because i noticed that for ecample the entery 11 is not releavint for example and i chose the bits according to each binary number.. here is what i have done so far , :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity mux_9_1 is
    port( inputt : in std_logic_vector(8 downto 0) ;
            selector : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
            outputt : out std_logic ) ;
end mux_9_1 ;

architecture arc_mux_9_1 of mux_9_1 is
    component my_mux_1 is
        port(   inputt : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) ;
                selector : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
                outputt : out std_logic ) ;
    end component ;

signal y : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) ;

begin
u0: my_mux port map (inputt(0)=>inputt(0),inputt(1)=>inputt(1),inputt(2)=>inputt(2),selector(0)=>selector(0),selector(1)=>selector(1),outputt=>y(0));
u1: my_mux port map (inputt(0)=>inputt(3),inputt(1)=>inputt(4),inputt(2)=>inputt(5),selector(0)=>selector(0),selector(1)=>selector(1),outputt=>y(1)) ;
u2: my_mux port map (inputt(0)=>inputt(6),inputt(1)=>inputt(7),inputt(2)=>inputt(8),selector(0)=>selector(0),selector(1)=>selector(1),outputt=>y(2)) ;
u3: my_mux port map (inputt(0)=>y(0),inputt(1)=>y(1),inputt(2)=>y(2),selector(0)=>selector(2),selector(1)=>selector(3),outputt=>outputt ) ;
end arc_mux_9_1 ;
```

any help of how i could do this in more simple way ?

Comment: Your specification is not complete: what is the mapping between `selector(3 downto 0)` and the 9 inputs to select from?

Comment: To quote Mark Lenard from Star Trek The Voyage Home "It is difficult to answer when one does not understand the question." See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). *any help of how i could do this in more simple way ?* isn't a specific question, nor is your code sample functional. What difficulty are you having completing your assignment? Are you required to use 3:1 muxes?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague as to what the problem is. I'm assuming you are getting an error that is telling you it can't find my_mux, because that's what I got. Replacing

```
u0: my_mux port map
```

with

```
u0: mu_mux_1 port map
```

allowed me to compile. I've run a test bench and it is fine.

Comment: What is the OP's question?  In addition to your method the default binding can also be corrected by renaming my_mux_1 to my_mux, or providing a binding indication as an architecture declarative item (a configuration specification): `for all: my_mux use entity work.my_mux_1;` The output of [the mux_9_1 is not fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrTm7.jpg) without changing u1, u2 and u3 selector(1 downto 0) association actuals and adding logic.

Comment: Took me a while to work out what you meant by "adding logic", I could see that the code that OP had written worked [i]as it was written[/i]. From your screenshot I understand now that OP would like to [i]avoid[/i] the "missing 11b" behaviour. Note I haven't said that that is the correct understanding! This becomes a lot more complicated if the OP HAS to use 3-1 muxes